# Is a single number a product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

This may seem like a strange question, but I was wondering if a single number $a\in \mathbb{C}$ can be seen as a product under the mathematical definition? Put differently, I am wondering if $\prod_{i=1}^{1}a_i$ is a product.

Comment: Yes, in fact there is even a trivial product of *no* numbers. Your product notation indexing over complex numbers is a bit unusual.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I guess you prefer $\prod_{i=1}^{1}a_i$ - I have changed it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Some might insist that "product" means strictly a binary operation (between two operands).  However a product operation (multiplication) is usually associative, so there is no difficulty with interpreting a "product" of any finite number of operands, especially one operand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We get to decide what technical terms mean and what notations mean, and it's convenient to define a product of any collection of numbers, including *even the empty collection!*

Just as an empty sum has value $0$ (the additive identity), an empty product has value $1$ (the multiplicative identity). For example, this motivates the factorial definitions $0! = 1$ and $1! = 1$.
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
A & \displaystyle{\prod_{a \in A} a} \\
\hline
\{\} & 1 = 1 \\
\{1\} & 1 \cdot 1 = 1 \\
\{1, 2\} & 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 2 \\
\{1, 2, 3\} & 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 6 \\
\qquad\vdots & \qquad\vdots \\
\{1, 2, \dots, n\} & 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdots n = n!
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I am not sure I understand your table. Why is the factor $1$ listed twice in the products when $1$ only appears once in the set? I explain $0!=1$ using the definition of functions as collections of ordered pairs and the empty function being a vacuous case. I think a better table would be powers of $x$ as $\prod x$.

Comment: Every product of a set $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ begins with the number $1$ and tacks on ${}\cdot a_k$ for each $k = 1, \dots, n$.

Comment: I *choose* to think of products this way so that the number of multiplications matches the number of elements in the set being multiplied.